# Should I use a Marionette CompositeView or Layout?

Tags: marionette

I'm using a marionette compositeview to display a collection, the code is below.

However, inside my collection I have 5 filters that are bound to events that then update the collection from the API.

The way I see it, theres two options, I would like opinions on which is better:

1) Use a layout view, somehow figure out how a compositeview can catch the filter views options and update the collection.
2) Use onRender to display the filter views and again catch the events in the compositeview

```
define(["marionette", "text!app/templates/posts/collection.html", "app/collections/posts", "app/views/posts/item"],
  function(Marionette, Template, Collection, Item) {
    "use strict"
    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({


      template: Template,
      itemView: Item,
      itemViewContainer: "tbody",


      filter: {
        from: 0,
        to: 15,
        publish_target: null,
        status: null,
        type: null,
        publish_from_date: null, //publish_from_date=2014-01-07
        publish_to_date: null, //publish_to_date=2014-01-07
        publish_from_time: null, //publish_from_time=01%3A00%20AM
        publish_to_time: null, //publish_to_time=12%3A30%20AM
        location_id: null,
        client_id: null
      },


      events: {
        'change .filterBy': 'onClickFilter',
        'change .filterByDate': 'onClickFilterDate'
      },


      collectionEvents: {
        'sync': 'hideLoading'
      },


      initialize: function(options) {

        //set loading, important we do this because we re-trigger the collection
        this.setLoading();

        // don't call a new collection unless its the init load, we lose collection automatically triggered events otherwise
        if (_.isEmpty(options) || !_.has(options, 'newCollection')) {
          this.collection = new Collection()
        }

        //strip any null key values from this.filter so the api doesnt filter crap
        this.filter = _.cleanNullFieldsFromObject(this.filter);

        //fetch the collection
        return this.collection.fetch({data: this.filter})
      },


      // date was triggered, so get the details
      onClickFilterDate: function() {
        var publishFrom = new Date($('#publish_from_date').val());
        var publishTo = new Date($('#publish_to_date').val());
        this.filter.publish_from_date = _.dateToYMD(publishFrom);
        this.filter.publish_to_date = _.dateToYMD(publishTo);
        this.filter.publish_from_time = _.dateToHM(publishFrom);
        this.filter.publish_to_time = _.dateToHM(publishTo);

        // from time is greater than two time, then fetch the collection
        if ( (publishFrom.getTime() / 1000) < (publishTo.getTime() / 1000) ) {
          this.initialize({newCollection: true});
        }
      },


      // a typical filter is clicked, so figure out whats happening
      onClickFilter: function (ev) {
        var type = $('#'+ev.currentTarget.id).data('type')
        switch (type) {
          case 'status':
            this.filter.status = $('#filterStatus').val();
            break;
          case 'publish_target':
            this.filter.publish_target = $('#filterPublishTarget').val();
            break;
          case 'type':
            this.filter.type = $('#filterType').val();
            break;
          case 'client_id':
            this.filter.client_id = $('#filterClientId').val();
            break;
          case 'location_id':
            this.filter.location_id = $('#filterLocationId').val();
            break;
        }
        this.initialize({newCollection: true});
      },


      hideLoading: function() {
        this.$el.find('.loading-latch').removeClass('loading-active');
      },


      //set loading by appending to the latch
      setLoading: function() {
        this.$el.find('.loading-latch').addClass('loading-active');
      }


    })
  })


define(["marionette", "text!app/templates/posts/item.html"],
  function(Marionette, Template) {
    "use strict"
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: Template,
      tagName: "tr",


      initialize: function () {
        this.model.set('statusReadable', this.model.getStatus());
      }

    })
  })
```

Comment: If you want to handle trigger events between marionette objects, I use the "vent".  The vent is internal to Marionette and allows for loosely coupling.

Comment: I personally prefer `Layouts` to `CompositeViews`, Layouts are more flexible and allow you to extend your view latter without much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went ahead and built both. I prefer the layout view.

Both have the concept of having a filter object that fetches and passes query params to the api.

Here are both solutions.

Using a layout that catches filter:changes vents to then update a filter object that gets passed into the collection view (I favour this because only the collection gets redrawn when a filter is changed)

http://pastebin.com/XNmQjs1i

Using a collection view that catches class events and redraws the view (I don't favour this because everything gets redrawn everytime the user changes a filter)

http://pastebin.com/WML2iiM4

I'm sure this might come in handy for marionette newbies, theres a lot of my learning poured into this. Enjoy.